# UIImageView in storyboard doesn't show image at start

Tags: ios, uiimageview, storyboard

I am writing an iOS app and I am using storyboards. In some screen I have an UIImageView for a banner. I set the image to the UIImageView in the menu in storyboard. (Not code behind)
But the Image isn't shown after the screen is loaded. After a while the image appears. 
Why is the image loaded so late? On other screen everything is ok.

best regards

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should set the background image for banner in file LaunchScreen.xib.

Comment: Why? Make no sense to change the LaunchScreen, when an UIImageView on a normal UIViewController has a problem, or?